# Netbeans will not compile maven fx projects but, compiles java fx projects just fine

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

As the title says I can compile/run regular java fx projects fine but, when i try to compile the defualt project netbeans gives you I get.

```
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project mtest: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred
```

I have tried reinstalling java and netbeans a couple times, checking JAVA_HOME environment variable, deleting the Netbeans cache, and trying different jdk's 8,9,and 12.

Not really sure what to do. Any ideas?

OS: Windows 10
jdk version: 9
Netbeans Nightly Build 201804200002